# Merge objects based on date in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, ecmascript-6

I have an object

```
{
  YHOO: [
    {
      date: Fri Apr 12 1996 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT),
      open: 25.25,
      high: 43,
      low: 24.5,
      close: 33,
      volume: 408720000,
      adjClose: 1.38,
      symbol: 'YHOO'
    },
    ...
    {
      date: Thu Nov 14 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST),
      open: 35.07,
      high: 35.89,
      low: 34.76,
      close: 35.69,
      volume: 21368600,
      adjClose: 35.69,
      symbol: 'YHOO'
    }
  ],
  GOOGL: [
    {
      date: Thu Aug 19 2004 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT),
      open: 100,
      high: 104.06,
      low: 95.96,
      close: 100.34,
      volume: 22351900,
      adjClose: 100.34,
      symbol: 'GOOGL'
    },
    ...
    {
      date: Thu Nov 14 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST),
      open: 1033.92,
      high: 1039.75,
      low: 1030.35,
      close: 1035.23,
      volume: 1166700,
      adjClose: 1035.23,
      symbol: 'GOOGL'
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

How do I alter this object so it becomes an array with

```
[
  {
    date: Fri Apr 12 1996 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT),
    YHOO: 33,
    GOOG: 100.34
  },
  ...
]
```

I know it can become a problem that they potentially not have the same dates, so I guess I should just say that one of the companies have the right dates, and then merge the other companies to these dates and omit those dates that are not in the already selected company.

I guess I should do something like

```
var data = [];
obj.YHOO.forEach((quote) => {
  data.push({
    date: quote.date,
    YHOO: quote.price,
    GOOG: ?
  });
});
```

and instead of the question mark, I can loop through all the objects in `array.GOOG` and check if the date matches `quote.date`.

The big problem is that this seems quite computational heavy and the names of the companies can vary, so I cannot guarantee that `YHOO` and `GOOG` are present.

Comment: `Fri Apr 12 1996 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)` and `Thu Aug 19 2004 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)` are different dates so on what basis did you group them?

Comment: It is a mistake. They have to be merged only if the dates match.

Comment: do you have data for each date through those years? is that what ... means?? if that is the case you could iterate through dates for each day and grab data from your json for each company that has data for the day.

Comment: Yes I have, but in very very very rare occasions, I could potentially miss a single date entry for one company, so I cannot be entirely sure if the is always 'perfect'.

Comment: Import the quantum computing library by building the binary from source and you'll be good.

Comment: you can also get the company names while iterating using the 'key' in jquery's $.each loop. Then have a couple of arrays with all variations of the name to mach against and one form to use if thre is a match.